# Edge colouring number of Cartesian product

Tags: graph-theory

The Cartesian product $G ×H$ of graphs $G$ and $H$ is a graph such that
the vertex set of $G ×H$ is the Cartesian product $V(G) × V(H)$; and
any two vertices $(u,u')$ and $(v,v')$ are adjacent in $G\times H$ if and only if either $u = v$ and $u'$ is adjacent with $v'$ in $H$, or $u' = v'$ and $u$ is adjacent with $v$ in $G$.

What is the Edge coloring number of $G×H$ and how do I prove this? And what about $G×K_2$?